# Perl: Server error at Net/Braintree HTTP module while integration

Tags: perl, paypal, payment-gateway, perl-module, braintree

I am newbie to Perl. I am working on integration of Braintree Payment gateway to an existing project. I'm following guides given n Braintre, its so clear and simple but I can't get it done. I have downloaded the Sample project from Github through the link: `https://github.com/braintree/braintree_perl_guide`

I am getting server errors while executing the app.pl file,

Steps followed:

1. Created a Sandbox account, got the Merchant id, Public key, Private key and the Configuration code.
2. Installed necessary modules needed to run the Perl script
3. Edited the app.pl file given and given my Merchant id and the associated keys.
4. Edited the form.tt file and given the Configuration code.
5. In terminal executed the command Perl app.pl, while pressing enter I got,

   > > Dancer 1.3124 server 79859 listening on locahost:3000
   > >     == Entering the development dance floor ...
6. From the browser connected to localhost:3000/ and have got the Braintree Credit Card Transaction Form.
7. Entered the details and clicked on submit button and suddenly got Error 500. "Unable to process your query".
8. How to resolve this please need your assistance.

My app.pl file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Dancer;
use Template;
use Net::Braintree;

my $config = Net::Braintree->configuration;

$config->environment("sandbox");
$config->merchant_id("wbjnmbzfnvs6zt56");
$config->public_key("smbbnwfhybb3h5ty");
$config->private_key("****");

get '/' => sub {
  template 'form'
};

post '/create_transaction' => sub {
  my $result = Net::Braintree::Transaction->sale({
    amount => "1000.00",
    credit_card => {
      number => param("number"),
      expiration_month => param("month"),
      expiration_year => param("year"),
      cvv => param("cvv")
    },
    options => {
      submit_for_settlement => 1
    }
  });

  my $success = $result->is_success ? "true" : "false";

  if ($result->is_success) {
    return "<h1>Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id . "</h1>"
  } else {
    return "<h1>Error: " . $result->message . "</h1>"
  }
};

Dancer->dance;
```

and my Form.tt file

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Braintree Credit Card Transaction Form</h1>
    <div>
      <form action="/create_transaction" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
        <p>
          <label>Card Number</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>CVV</label>
          <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
          <input type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="year" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var braintree = Braintree.create('MIIBCgKCAQEA1E9xWJbLZeJVM9VuITkFTLbYhbxERQ64hKqDL495BTwJBJaTz+Y29U555ekRaAGeOzuRAP7wgsOhyKsvKn3w7i3JVakdPYJSLMKgjqrQOTxSxUaUn+qpb+etJiALC3lsckmh04Io/x8B16hZAKhjQTB1XUZtuEcT8Pe0ObPlnZpWPXayMGElyBQnS/AaLWE7VZiq7ezqiRl5atp7RatAUACvfTkpRdlBAw9XuaEpgKPLPWtj8CQCJk3LDYWjrLvwGKQ/LW/uPoBpfVmqbbSVe1sAaZcdMcPyqL0viYn3QSIkiLhz8SvCJExo4XaMBSGOENg2bCbBWNHSNiJzrdZA4wIDAQAB');
      braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 500 typically means something dreadful happened on the server side.  What kind of logging does braintree have from their development console?  I notice that you didn't validate any of the data before passing it to braintree. That could affect your outcomes.

Comment: I work at Braintree. I'd suggest you [get in touch with out support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). What do you see in the console / log files when you run the script? It sounds like your server is throwing an error when you submit the form to it.

Comment: @agf, Yes of course I interacted with the Braintree support team. They responded as "I’m actually not seeing any requests coming from you to our Gateway in the logs. If you could, send me the snippet of code that is generating the error so I can test it on this side and see what is going on".

Comment: @agf, In console log i got the following error logs, ServerError at /Library/Perl/5.12/Net/Braintree/HTTP.pm line 62
Net::Braintree::HTTP::check_response_code('Net::Braintree::HTTP=HASH(0x7fcb151186f8)', 500) called at /Library/Perl/5.12/Net/Braintree/HTTP.pm line 48
Net::Braintree::HTTP::make_request('Net::Braintree::HTTP=HASH(0x7fcb151186f8)', '/customers/', 'HASH(0x7fcb1512d398)', 'POST') called at /Library/Perl/5.12/Net/Braintree/HTTP.pm line 13

Comment: Can you edit your code snippet above and copy / paste in your merchant ID and public key (not private key) then post a comment to let me know? I'll take a look in our logs.

Comment: I have edited the code with my merchant id and public key.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Its an proxy issue and after by passing the proxy server, it worked for me. The API IP address is unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Per comments, the error was actually caused by a proxy issue.  Bypassing the proxy resolved the problem.